# Android Studio: как решить проблему с импортом FireBase SDK в build.gradle (project)?

Tags: android-studio, firebase-database, firebase-android

Пытаюсь подключить свое приложение к базе данных, где будут храниться данные для входа (имя, фамилия, E-mail и пароль). Зарегистрировался, все заполнил, скачал файл .json и импортировал его, и теперь пришло время вставить код в build.gradle, как проекта, так и модуля. Проблемы на данном этапе возникли с файлом проекта. Там у меня до этого находился код с плагинами вот такой:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false
}
```

Ну а я решил вставить код из Firebase, не удаляя плагинов, синхронизировал его, и начал получать ошибки одну за другой. Сначала вставил так:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }
    dependencies {
        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }
}
```

и получил ошибку "startup failed:
build file 'D:\SatriaAdhiPradana\build.gradle': 7: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script". Прочитал ее внимательно, понял, что блоки bildscript надо размещать до плагинов и переставил так:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }
    dependencies {
        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }
}
```

Пошла во всю синхронизация, думал все сделал правильно, и вдруг - возникает очень длинная ошибка (решил не помещать ее здесь, чтобы вопрос уложился по количеству символов и  опубликовался.

Потом внимательно прочитал, что эту штуку надо вставить, как плагин, и включил его в сам код
plugins вот так:

```
{
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
            google()  // Google's Maven repository

            mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

        }
        dependencies {
            // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
            google()  // Google's Maven repository

            mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

        }
    }
}
```

Получил вот такую ошибку:

```
  build file 'D:\SatriaAdhiPradana\build.gradle': 8: only id(String), alias(Provider), or alias(ProviderConvertible) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block
```

В связи с этим возникает вопрос, что я делаю не так? Куда деть эти плагины? Надо ли сначала в Android SDK подключать возможность связываться с базой данных?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь включить плагин `google-services` старым способом.
нужно в `build.gradle` уровня проекта добавить последней строчкой в `plugins`

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
```

также в `build.gradle(:app)` нужно добавить в `plugins`

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Все остальные добавленные блоки нужно удалить

Comment: А maven() и связанный с ним url тоже зашит в этот плагин?